# How to manage several Terraform states

Tags: terraform

I am using Terraform to automatically deploy an Azure Resource Group with a VM. It's working great and now I'm onto my next step.

The purpose of my project is to provide users with a means to deploy their user-defined Azure RGs. So a typical user will use my portal to enter some details on a form about how they'd like their RG to be called, which location, username and SSH keys for the VM, etc., and then on the backend I'm populating a Terraform template with their input, then running `terraform apply`.

So far so good since I'm the only user.

When this goes into production, there'll be several users. They can create one or more resource groups and I was wondering how is best to handle this with Terraform. Should I just create one folder per user and RG (or some entry on a DB), so I can keep the state there? Or is there a better way to do this? I'll need this in order to do things like destroying a user resource, or checking a resource's status, etc.

I'm going with Terraform and I'd like to not have to use the Azure SDK if I can avoid it.

Comment: Have you looked into [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html) yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a terraform backend https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/index.html to store the state into the cloud storage solution of your choice. Using some $var to identify the deployment and this token as one of the URI element. For instance, user 'A' could have the state saved in gs://bucket/A/state , that did the trick for us using GCS.